# Falling back to another field on null with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a table with data that can be edited, `body` and `body_edited`. When the content is added to the table, the `body` field is always present and `body_edited` is null. `body_edited` is for a small portion of content that will potentially be changed in the future and used for public-facing content while maintaining the original.

I need to search this data in such a way that `body_edited` is used for the search but falls back to `body` when `body_edited` doesn't exist. I've found how to put in a dummy value for null fields, but I don't see how I can fall back to another field with just a query.

The `body` field will be maintained for legacy reasons. Creating a third field when importing the data from SQL has been brought up as an option, but it will substantially increase the amount of space needed for storage.

Is there any way to achieve this through a query across two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this using `should` and `exists` clauses. Let's assume you have two following documents:

```
// Document 1
{
  "body": "quick brown fox",
  "body_edited": null
}

// Document 2
{
  "body": "quick brown fox",
  "body_edited": "jumps over the lazy dog"
}
```

Here is the example of a search query for terms "brown fox":

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        "match": {
          "body_edited": "brown fox"
        }
      },
      {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "body": "brown fox"
            }
          },
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "body_edited"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This query will return only first document despite the fact that `body` field in the document 2 also meet our search criteria.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this once I get a chance to test it.